# Bios unable to find Ubuntu 64bit CD, with 32bit installed already

Tags: installation, 12.10, 64-bit, uninstall, 32-bit

My friend and I are having a problem, where his PC won't find Ubuntu 64bit CD, after having installed 32 bit already by accident.

He gets a BIOS message saying "Media test failed. Check cable" and afterwards tells us "Unable to find OS", and then it goes to boot Ubuntu 32bit.

When I'm putting the CD in my PC, it boots fine, to the Install screen.

Packard Bell Easynote LM:

- AMD Phenom II X2 N660
- 6GB DDR3 RAM
- 640 GB HDD.

Comment: Post your friend's computer hardware specifications.

Comment: It's a Packard Bell Easynote LM - AMD Phenom II X2 N660, with 6GB DDR3 RAM, 640 GB HDD. Updating question too.

Comment: Have you done as the bios suggests and checked the drive and cabling?  This seems to be a simple hardware problem accessing the cd and has nothing to do with there already being 32 bit Ubuntu installed.

Comment: I found it weird, that the CD with 32bit just recently worked fine in the old PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit, and then upgrading from there, to Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Here's a link on how to. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade/